# Hadoop and database

Tags: database, hadoop

I am currently looking at an issue where I am trying to integrate hadoop with a database, since hadoop offers parallelism but not performance. I was referring the paper of hadoopDB. Hadoop usually takes a file and splits it into chunks and places these chunks in different data nodes. During processing the namenode tells the location where a chunk might be found and runs a map on that node. I am looking at a possiblility of the user telling the namenode which datanode to run the map on and the namenode either runs the map to get the data from a file or a database. Can you kindly tell me whether it is feasible to tell the namenode which datanode to run the map ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would like to tie a map/reduce task to a particular node. What happens if that particular node goes down? In Hadoop the map/reduce operations cannot be tied to a particular node in the cluster that what makes Hadoop more scalable.

Also, you might want to take a look @ [Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) for importing/exporting between Hadoop and Database.

Comment: Thank you @praveen I have a scenario where there is data distributed across and hence when a query arrives the relevant parts of the query should fetch the data from the different databases. Hence I have a need to access particular nodes and query those nodes. I can later add the replication functionality to it so that even if a node goes down I can still retrieve the data from the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to query data from a distributed data store, then why don't you consider storing your data into [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/) which is a distributed data base built on top of Hadoop and HDFS. It stores data into HDFS in the background and gives query semantics like a big database. In that case you don't have to worry about issuing queries to the right data node. The query semantics of HBase (also known as hadoop database will take care of the same).

For easy querying and storing data into Hbase and if your data is timeseries data, then you can also consider using [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) which is a wrapper around Hbase and provides you with easy tag based query semantics as well as integrates nicely with GNUPlot, to give you graph like visualization of your data.

Hbase is very well suited for random reads/writes to a very large distributed data store however, if your queries operate on bulk writes/reads [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) maybe a well suited solution for your case. Similar to Hbase, it is also built on top of Hadoop Map Reduce and HDFS and converts each query to underlying map-reduce jobs. The best thing about Hive is that it provides SQL like semantics and you can query just like you would do on a relational database.
As far as organization of data and a basic introduction to the features of Hive is concerned you may like to go through the following points:

- Hive adds structure to the data stored on HDFS. The schema of tables is stored in a separate metadata store. It converts SQL like semantics to multiple map reduce jobs running on HDFS in the backend.
- Traditional databases follow the schema on write policy where once a schema is designed for a table, at the time of writing data itself, it is checked whether the data to be written conforms to the pre-defined schema. If it does not, the write is rejected.
  In case of Hive, it is the opposite. It uses the schema on read policy. Both the policies have their own individual trade-offs. In case of schema on write, load time is more and loads are slower because schema conformance is verified at the time of loading data. However, it provides faster query time because it can index data based on predefined columns in the schema, however there may be cases where the indexing cannot be specified while populating the data initially and this is where schema on read comes in handy. It provides the option to have 2 different schema present on the same underlying data depending on the kind of analysis required.
- Hive is well suited for bulk access, updates of data as a new update requires a completely new table to be constructed. Also, query time is slower as compared to traditional databases because of the absence of indexing.
- Hive stores the metadata into a relational database called the “Metastore”.
- There are 2 kinds of tables in Hive:

  Managed tables - Where the data file for the table is predefined and is moved to the hive warehouse directory on HDFS (in general, or any other hadoop filesystem). When a table is deleted, in that case, the metadata and the data both are deleted from the filesystem.

  External tables - Here you can create data into the table lazily. There is no data moved to the Hive warehouse directory in this case and the schema/metadata is loosely coupled to the actual data. When a table is deleted, only the metadata gets deleted and the actual data is left untouched. It becomes helpful in cases if you want the data to be used by multiple databases. Another reason of using the same maybe when you need multiple schemas on the same underlying data.